# team foundation 2010 read only workitems user account mismatch

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying getting ready to move my TFS 2010 database for the third time to its final perminent server, however, I am running into a very annoying user issue. When I restored the new system as a test I connected my Visual Studio IDE to the new server (same name as the old one) and tested and got that system working properly. Now when I go to the old server now I can connect and see everything - but I no longer have permissions to create work items or edit items.

I can use Visual Studio 2012 just fine as well as the Microsoft Test Center 2010 to edit items. I've experienced this before with my local system tfs at home and got around it by changing the user name I log into on my computer and then adding permissions for that new username.

Since these the user id's are workstation accounts - not domain accounts each system has its own user guid even though they might have the same account name. I noticed in VS 2010 the workitem in history show modified by unknown user - however it has the username in VS2012. It seems that connecting to both systems might somehow made the user matching between my domain user account and workgroup user account break.

I am about to roll to the new server and am concerned that my userbase will not be able to modify items in VS2010. I cannot use the workaround I did before since I can't have everyone create a new username.

Any help would be appreciated - as I am sure I am not the only one with a workgroup not domain tfs system that has run into this issue before.

Comment: I have done the following to try to clear out the user 1. user tfsconfig /identities to remap old domain accounts 2. set the windows identify for this tfs system to the full login credentials (servername/username), and 3. cleared the visual studio 2010 settings to have the IDE default to the original user settings